# include option for ng test is not working

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

I am trying to run unit tests using Karma and Jasmine using the ng test. when I issue the following command:

```
ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --main ./src/main/resources/public/scripts/xyz/workspace/commons/interceptors/mgr.ng.spec.ts
```

It works without any issues.

When I try the following command to run all scripts in that directory:

```
ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --include=src/main/resources/public/scripts/xyz/workspace/commons/interceptors/*.ng.spec.ts
```

I get the following error:

```
Specified patterns: "src/main/resources/public/scripts/xyz/workspace/commons/interceptors/*.ng.spec.ts" did not match any spec files
```

Any idea what is happening here? I tried many variations and it does not look like the include option is working at all.

Answer (score 5):

The following is the command to run the test files under a particular folder and all its subfolder/subdirectory

```
ng test --include='src/app/modulefolder/**/*.spec.ts'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `ng test --watch=false --code-coverage --include="src/main/resources/public/scripts/xyz/workspace/commons/interceptors/*.ng.spec.ts"`

It would also be beneficial if you would post your project structure.

Answer (score 1):

Oh don't you need to add quotation marks around your path? Also if you want, you can use this other way of using `--include`

`ng test --include relative_or_absolute_path_here`

or

`ng test --include="relative_or_absolute_path_here"`

https://angular.io/cli/test

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is supported yet.

One solution here: 
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3603#issuecomment-523794137

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the solution provided in that link throws and "unhandled exception.." I tried: the following:  ng test ./src/main/resources/public/scripts/xyz/workspace/commons/interceptors

Answer (score 0):

`ng test --include=src/app/my-folder`

works for me.  No quotes.  No `*`.

[Per the angular docs,](https://angular.io/cli/test)

> Globs of files to include, relative to workspace or project root.
> There are 2 special cases:
>
> - ***when a path to directory is provided, all spec files ending ".spec.@(ts|tsx)" will be included***
> - when a path to a file is provided, and a matching spec file exists it will be included instead

Note, I tested in Powershell.  Might need escape sequence and different slahes on different OS's/terminals.

Answer (score 0):

to test all spec files in current director, and subfolders:

```
ng test --include **/*.spec.ts
```